# appium android python. action.tap(btn).perform() vs btn.click() what is better?

Tags: android, python, appium, selendroid

So, by authomating in my appium android python tests 
I've noticed that both cases work well like so:

```
btn = self.driver.find_element_by_id('path') # element
1:
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.tap(btn).perform()  # tap on button 
2:
btn.click()  # click on button
```

Could anyone explain what case is better and way?

Comment: Use click if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works by using `click()` then use it. i don't see any reason to use action class for just `click()`.